# How do you save the model output for a class "MaxEnt" object or “BRT”, or “ randomForest” from package ‘dismo’?

Tags: dismo

How do you save the model output for a class  "MaxEnt" object or "BRT", or "randomForest" from Package 'enmSdmX' ---object of S3 class gbm-- Package 'dismo'. The enmSdmX uses the functions in the dismo package.

I can’t save it using the vector it is stored in as a data.frame or rds. When you try to run the vector, it is stored in it says ‘the html output is not available’. But it works with the “predictEnmSdm” function. So it is there I am just not using best practices with this package.

```
MxEnt_Vars <- trainMaxEnt(
data = train_Data,
resp = 'presBg',
preds = Adapt_West_CNC_Vars,
regMult = 2.5, verbose = TRUE,
cores = 1
)

MxEntMap_Vars <- predictEnmSdm(MxEnt _Vars, Climate)
```

Thank you for any help